# Apache POI Pivot Tables- How to use the "In-Between" Value Filter in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to design a pivot table using Apache POI, and what I want to do is to initially print the sum value which is greater than a certain number, as well as less than a certain number. However, when I try and do this, the filters cancel each other out, which means that sum values are printed that should not be there. For example, if I want the sum to be between 2 and 5, the sum value of 1, as well as numbers greater than 5, both get printed out. Here is the code that explains my problem:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.spring;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTAutoFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataFields;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ExcelAutoPivotPracticeApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     SpringApplication.run(ExcelAutoPivotPracticeApplication.class, args);

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("MyExcel5.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "IntVal", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  4d},
        new Object[]{"B", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  1d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
     else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer)
         cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[c]);
    }
   }
AreaReference a = new AreaReference("A1:D9", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    a, 
    new CellReference("E4"));
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCompact(false);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setCompactData(false);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setOutline(true);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setOutlineData(true);
   for (CTPivotField pf: pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList())
   {
    System.out.println("FOO");
    pf.setCompact(false);
    pf.setOutline(true);
    pf.setDefaultSubtotal(true);
   }
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters filters =
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter field = filters.addNewFilter();
   field.setId(0);
   field.setFld(1);
   field.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_BETWEEN);
   field.setIMeasureFld(0);
    CTFilterColumn myCol = field.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   CTCustomFilters myFilter2= myCol.addNewCustomFilters();
   CTCustomFilter custFilt = myFilter2.addNewCustomFilter();
   CTCustomFilter custFilt2 = myFilter2.addNewCustomFilter();
   custFilt.setOperator(STFilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   custFilt.setVal("2");
   custFilt2.setOperator(STFilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   custFilt2.setVal("5");
   field.getAutoFilter().setRef("A1");
   field.getAutoFilter().getFilterColumnArray(0).setColId(0);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

This is the pivot table that gets printed as a result of running this code:
[image]

If you have any idea on how to help me with this, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Well, how to get what needs to be set for the `*.xlsx` file? The `*.xlsx` is simply a `ZIP` archive. So one can unzip the  `*.xlsx` and have a look what is inside it.

So do what you need using `Excel`'s `GUI`, save the `*.xlsx`, then unzip it and have a look at `/xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml`. There you will find the following filter setting:

```
<filters count="1">
 <filter fld="1" type="valueBetween" evalOrder="-1" id="1" iMeasureFld="0">
  <autoFilter ref="A1">
   <filterColumn colId="0">
    <customFilters and="1">
     <customFilter operator="greaterThanOrEqual" val="2"/>
     <customFilter operator="lessThanOrEqual" val="5"/>
    </customFilters>
   </filterColumn>
  </autoFilter>
 </filter>
</filters>
```

So `customFilters` needs the setting that the following filters are `AND` linked. This is what your code does not set yet.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTDataField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreatePivotTableFilter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./MyExcelV2.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "IntVal", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }
   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  4d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  1d},
    new Object[]{"B", "B2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1),  5d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C1", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  2d},
    new Object[]{"B", "C2", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2),  8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
     else if (rowData[c] instanceof Integer)
         cell.setCellValue((Integer) rowData[c]);
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference("A1:D9", 
    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), 
    new CellReference("F4"));
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
   pivotTable.addColLabel(2);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);

   //create filters
   CTPivotFilters filters = CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();

   //set custom value filter
   int filtersCount = 0; // to count filters
   CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
   filter.setId(0); // filter needs Id
   filter.setFld(1); // filter on column B level
   filter.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_BETWEEN);
   filter.setIMeasureFld(0); //internal measure field is 0 (first data field) = Sum; 1 would be Average
   CTFilterColumn filterColumn = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   filterColumn.setColId(0); // filterColumn need colId
   CTCustomFilters customFilters= filterColumn.addNewCustomFilters();
   customFilters.setAnd(true); // following filters are AND linked
   CTCustomFilter customFilter = customFilters.addNewCustomFilter();
   customFilter.setOperator(STFilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   customFilter.setVal("2");
   customFilter = customFilters.addNewCustomFilter();
   customFilter.setOperator(STFilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL);
   customFilter.setVal("5");

   filtersCount++;
   filters.setCount(filtersCount); // set filters count

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```