# How to add filter on count column in pivot table?

Tags: java, excel, filter, apache-poi, pivot-table

I need to filter pivot table based on count column values.
I have tried couple of code samples from google but nothing worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZihg.png)
How to implement this filter using apache poi in java.

Below is the sample working code to generate pivot table on dummy data.

```
package com.technia.upgradetool.export;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import com.technia.upgradetool.Analyzer;

public class CreatePivotTableFilterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ItemFilter.xlsx")) {

            Sheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
            Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            Object[][] data = new Object[][]
                { new Object[]
                            { "Header", "Complexity" }, new Object[]
                            { "A", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "A", "Low" }, new Object[]
                            { "C", "Moderate" }, new Object[]
                            { "D", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "A", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "B", "Low" }, new Object[]
                            { "G", "Low" }, new Object[]
                            { "G", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "G", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "G", "High" }, new Object[]
                            { "G", "Low" }, new Object[]
                            { "H", "Low" }, new Object[]
                            { "H", "Low" } };
            for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
                row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
                Object[] rowData = data[r];
                for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
                    cell = row.createCell(c);
                    if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
                    } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Number) {
                        cell.setCellValue(((Number) rowData[c]).doubleValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0),
                    new CellReference(data.length - 1, data[0].length - 1),
                    SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet) pivotSheet).createPivotTable(areaReference,
                    new CellReference("A4"), dataSheet);

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 1, "Count of complexity");
            // Method addColLabel removes the dataField setting. So we need set it new.
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition()
                .getPivotFields()
                .getPivotFieldArray(1)
                .setDataField(true);

            workbook.write(fileout);
            fileout.close();

            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("ItemFilter.xlsx"));

        }

    }
}
```

I need to show only rows which has complexity greater than 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYz5m.png)

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to reproduce your problem. See my answer to your previous question for how a Minimal, Reproducible Example should look like.

Comment: I have added sample code expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Apache POI Pivot Tables- How to use the "In-Between" Value Filter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921076/apache-poi-pivot-tables-how-to-use-the-in-between-value-filter-in-java/63924592#63924592) I have shown how to set a value filter for pivot table using Apache POI.

Adopted to your example, that would be:

Run your code.

In result `Itemfilter.xlsx` do what you want using Excel GUI. Save the file.

Unzip `Itemfilter.xlsx` and have a look into `/xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml`. There you will find:

```
<filters count="1">
 <filter fld="0" type="valueGreaterThan" evalOrder="-1" id="1" iMeasureFld="0">
  <autoFilter ref="A1">
   <filterColumn colId="0">
    <customFilters>
     <customFilter operator="greaterThan" val="2"/>
    </customFilters>
   </filterColumn>
  </autoFilter>
 </filter>
</filters>
```

Now try creating that using following classes:

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilters;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCustomFilter;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTFilterColumn;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STFilterOperator;
```

Code:

```
...
   //create filters
   CTPivotFilters filters = CTPivotFilters.Factory.newInstance();

   //set custom value filter
   int filtersCount = 0; // to count filters
   CTPivotFilter filter = filters.addNewFilter();
   filter.setId(0); // filter needs Id !ToDo - handle carefully
   filter.setFld(0); // filter on column level 0 - first row label
   filter.setType(org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STPivotFilterType.VALUE_GREATER_THAN);
   filter.setIMeasureFld(0); //internal measure field is 0 - first data field
   CTFilterColumn filterColumn = filter.addNewAutoFilter().addNewFilterColumn();
   filterColumn.setColId(0); // filterColumn need colId !ToDo - handle carefully
   CTCustomFilters customFilters= filterColumn.addNewCustomFilters();
   CTCustomFilter customFilter = customFilters.addNewCustomFilter();
   customFilter.setOperator(STFilterOperator.GREATER_THAN);
   customFilter.setVal("2");

   filtersCount++;
   filters.setCount(filtersCount); // set filters count

   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setFilters(filters);              
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
One more information I was looking for, can we give pivot table reference to the charts using apache poi. I am generating charts currently by giving cell references , instead of that can we give pivot table reference directly?

Comment: @pranavs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491423/is-it-possible-to-create-pivot-chart-with-source-data-as-pivot-table-using-apach/70504913#70504913

Comment: Yes I had referred this thread but its not working. Getting below error and pivot chart is removed from excel on opening.
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)

Comment: @pranavs: Just tested again. Works for me using Apache POI 5.2.5 and opened using Excel 2016 as well as Excel 365 without any problem.

Comment: There are no errors on the console. I have the same apache poi version 5.2.5 and using excel version -
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit 
Is there any alternative solution for chart generation using pivot table reference?

Comment: @pranavs: From Apache POI 4.1.2  up to 5,2,4 there was this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432090/excel-files-created-with-apache-poi-wont-show-line-chart-anymore/77432631#77432631. Thus one needs implement the two lines of code to repair axes number format settings, But with version 5,2,5 this bug was fixed,